# How do you modify query results before passing it to a view in Laravel, with Blade?

Tags: php, laravel-10

Controller:

```php
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = TaskResource::collection(Task::all());

        return view('task.index', ['tasks' => $tasks]);
    }
```

TaskResource:

```php
class TaskResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'created_by' => [
                'id' => $this->createdBy->id,
                'name' => $this->createdBy->name,
            ],
            'status' => [
                'id' => $this->status_id,
                'text' => TaskStatuses::$statusObject[$this->status_id],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

and then the blade:

```html
                            @foreach ($tasks as $task)
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="fit"><a href="#">{{ $task->name }}</a></td>
                                    <td class="fit">{{ $task->status->text }}</td>
                                    <td class="">{{ $task->assigned_to }}</td>
                                    <td class="fit">{{ $task->created_at }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

but I get an error saying `Attempt to read property "text" on null` . Turns out, the resource does nothing to it. If I just remove the entire thing and do "foo"=>"bar", and return that in the TaskResource, it doesn't give a damn about it, just continues to use the data as it is originally. The created_at is getting rendered in the blade too, even tho I didn't specify it in the resource, so it's 100% not doing anything with it...

I just want to format my data before sending it to the view... I'm not able to find the solution, Idk what I'm missing...

Comment: Your error is likely on this line: `$task->status->text`, but `$task->status` is `null`, and `null->text` is not valid PHP... The `$task` instance that you're currently iterating on via `@foreach($tasks as $task)` doesn't have an associated `status`. Instead of `Task::all()`, try `Task::has('status')->get()` and see if your code works as written.

Comment: Task will never "have" a status. IT is not a column. Let's get away from the status->text and such, right? I want to include "foo"=>"bar" in every single task, and return only the id, name and foo. So it would have data as: id=>1, name=>asd, foo=>bar. Even tho I specify the foo=>bar in the resource, it does *not* include the foo=>bar in the response, and gives back every information, not only the id,name,foo. Am I making sense? I just want to include data to them, nothing more, nothing less. I'm beginning to think I'm losing my mind, noone seems to understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Or look at it another way, if I return this in the TaskResource: ```return ['name' => $this->name,'description' => $this->description,'foo'=>'bar'];``` then how come I can do `$task->created_at` in blade? where does that `created_at` come from? and how come `'foo'` is null?

Comment: So did you `@dd($tasks)` or `@dd($task)` in your blade? "_Transform the resource into an array_" and "_toArray()_" ... have you tried accessing it as an array? Do resources work in Blade, I thought those were API resources

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed the resource logic on this setting `'status' => [...]`; I should have read this a bit more carefully; that's on me. This error gets posted on Stackoverflow multiple times per week, and it's usually the same reason; iterating over a Collection of Models and trying to access a `null` Relationship, like `$task->status->text`, but I see now that in your case, `status` is not a Relationship (or maybe it is, I'm unfamilar with `Resource::collection(Model::all())` and how that uses `->toArray()`).

Comment: in my controller when I do this: `        $tasks = TaskResource::collection(Task::all());

        foreach ($tasks as $task) {
            return $task;
        }`

it returns this: `{"data":{"name":"Quae est aut sit rem non doloribus.","foo":"bar"}}`
but when I try to change it to this: `return $task->foo` it is suddenly empty, nothing is returned.

If I @dd($task) in blade, it returns the "TaskResource", which has the `original` and `attributes` vars in it, unaffected by the resource, like I did Task::all(); instead of the resource collection.

Comment: It's ok @TimLewis. Yes, it is not a relationship, just an ID and a simple text I want to include in it. Or just basically 'foo'=>'bar'.

Comment: I'd happily accept any other solution to modify the data I'm passing to the blade (globally), so I don't have to basically copy-paste a `transform` with a callback to every method I have, just to add 'foo'=>'bar' to it. Originally I was using transform, which made it so the "attribute" got the 'foo'=>'bar' into it and I'd access it by doing $task->status['text'], but doing this transform for every modification, on every method is just a lot. that's why I thought using a resource that modifies the data like that would've helped me :D I guess I was wrong?